# How to encode seasonal journal citation with Schema.org?

Tags: schema.org, citations

Anyone have experience encoding journal metadata with Schema.org properties (using JSON-LD) when the journal issue is “Spring”, “Summer” or “Fall/Winter”?

How would you encode it since [`issueNumber`](https://schema.org/issueNumber) isn’t really a match?

As an example, here’s a Chicago style citation that includes a volume/issue and a season/year date:

> McBride, Matthew. “‘Female Brethren’: Gender Dynamics in a Newly Integrated Missionary Force, 1898–1915.” Journal of Mormon History 44, no. 4 (October 2018): 40–67.

Answer (score 2):

I would represent the seasonal aspect of the issue in the `name` of the `PublicationIssue`.

This example is issue 4 of volume 44.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Article",
    "@id": "#article",
    "name": "‘Female Brethren’: Gender Dynamics in a Newly Integrated Missionary Force, 1898–1915.",
    "author": "McBride, Matthew.",
    "ispartOf": {
        "@id": "#issue",
        "@type": "PublicationIssue",
        "name": "Journal of Mormon History 44, no. 4 (October 2018)",
        "issueNumber": "4",
        "datePublished": "2018",
        "isPartOf": {
            "@id": "#periodical",
            "@type": ["PublicationVolume","Periodical"],
            "name": "Journal of Mormon History 44",
            "volumeNumber": "44"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nice to see you here, Richard :) I edited your answer to fix small errors in the JSON-LD. If I did something wrong, you can always [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful for you to use structured data for the type **[Dataset](https://schema.org/Dataset)**. 
For example:

```js
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org/",
  "@type":"Dataset",
  "name":"Female Brethren",
  "description":"Gender Dynamics in a Newly Integrated Missionary Force, 1898–1915",
  "url":"https://exem.com/dataset/gender9815",
  "sameAs":"https://zzz.net",
  "keywords":[
     "Gender",
     "Dynamics",
     "Missionary",
     "Force"
  ],
  "creator":{
     "@type":"Organization",
     "url": "https://rtd.com/",
     "name":"The name of your Organization",
     "contactPoint":{
        "@type":"ContactPoint",
        "contactType": "customer service",
        "telephone":"zzz",
        "email":"xxx@ggg.nn"
     }
  },
  "includedInDataCatalog":{
     "@type":"DataCatalog",
     "name":"Journal of Mormon History 44, no. 4"
  },
  "distribution":[
     {
        "@type":"DataDownload",
        "encodingFormat":"CSV",
        "contentUrl":"http://ex.com/info/info.jsp"
     },
     {
        "@type":"DataDownload",
        "encodingFormat":"XML",
        "contentUrl":"http://ex.com/info/info.xml"
     }
  ],
  "temporalCoverage":"1898-01-01/1915-12-18",
  "spatialCoverage":{
     "@type":"Place",
     "geo":{
        "@type":"GeoShape",
        "box":"18.0 -65.0 72.0 172.0"
     }
  }
}
```

Here are listed only two formats: CSV and XML. However, you can use other formats.

**[This type is supported by Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/dataset)**.

Read more **[Google search adds dataset schema support to search results](https://searchengineland.com/google-search-adds-dataset-schema-support-to-search-results-302906)**.